# Can't set response cookies inside promise ExpressJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cookies, promise

So I have an app.post leading to this file:

```html
'use strict';


function login(req, res, next) {
    console.log("This line is executed");
    makePromise().then(function(result){
        res.cookie("key", "val");
        console.log("This line isn't executed");
        res.send("Ok");
    });
    next();
}

function makePromise() {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        resolve("Done");
    });
}

module.exports = login;
```

But when I request the url it only executes the first console.log line and then returns 404 without sending the cookie or executing the rest of the code. This doesn't happen when I try setting the cookie outside the promise.

FYI: Obviously this isn't the code I'm actually trying to achieve but a sample that includes the relevant part for my problem. In my code I have to find something in my database in order to send to cookie so I have to use promise unless someone can help me find a better way.

Thanks,
Gur.

Comment: The first console.log() that is being executed, is that within the URL you're requesting? 404 = not found so double check the path of the url you are requesting. If the page is not found then it isn't being used/run so no console logs from that page since it doesn't exist.

Comment: firstly, Promises are inherently asynchronous - secondly add a `.catch` to that `makePromise().then(-snip- ... your existing code here ... -snip-).catch(err=>console.error(err))` to see if `res.cookie("key", "val");` is perhaps throwing an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `next()` BEFORE you call `res.send()`.  You want to only call one of those.  If you're sending a response, then don't call `next()` at all because calling `next()` tells Express to continue routing with other handlers (ultimately ending up with a 404 handler if no handler is found that actually handles it).

So, remove the call to `next()` and make sure nothing else is also trying to send a response for the request:

```
function login(req, res, next) {
    console.log("This line is executed");
    makePromise().then(function(result){
        res.cookie("key", "val");
        console.log("This line will execute after your promise resolves");
        res.send("Ok");
    }).catch(function(err) {
        console.log("Got error: ", err);
        res.status(500).send("Error");
    });
}
```

And, remember that promises always resolve asynchronously (on some future tick).  That's why your call to `next()` was happening before your promise called its `.then()` handler.